# Passing data from an action to Filter - Yii

Tags: php, filter, yii

I'm looking for a suggestion on how to solve an issue I have. I have a filter that executes a DB check on the `postFilter` function. The filter basically sees if an email should be generated and send out a template set up by the site admin. This function is working as expected.

The issue i have is there are some actions that i need to pass specific data to the email template that is only exposed within the action. My initial idea was to assign the needed values to a system parameter in the form of an array that could be accessed from filter function. The issue with this would be documenting each action that passes extra data.

I just wondering if there is more elegant solution... I would like to keep the system as flexible as possible for the user so if there was a way the user could setup a catch on the `preFilter` action that could then pass the needed information to `postFilter`.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is generated within the action there's no avoiding the fact that the action *has* to cooperate somehow in order to make the data available to whatever code ends up sending the email. Therefore I can't see how it would be possible to *not* have to document that "action X exposes data Y".

A very simple but at the same time quite adequate solution would be to have a pair of `setContextData` / `getContextData` functions on the base controller; actions set the data and the postfilter reads it.

Comment: Thanks.. I was hoping that there was an built in function in Yii to do something like this..